# Problema bucle JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bucles, checkbox

Tengo un bucle el cual dependiendo del `checkbox` que seleccione me devuelve un `alert` y habilita un `input`, la cosa es, que si yo el nombre del `checkboxProducto` lo concateno con la variable `i` no me funciona, en cambio si lo concateno con la variable `f` que sería el número exacto de `id` del `checkbox`, sí que funciona.

Lo que no entiendo es, cómo teniendo puesto que realicé *5 iteraciones*, *no entre en el input 3* mediante la variable `i` y pero sí con la variable `f`.

```js
function checkBox() {
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++)  {
    f=38;
    var CheckBox = document.getElementById("myCheckboxProducto"+i);
    if (checkbox.checked == true){
      alert(i);
      document.getElementById('inputBoxProducto38').disabled=false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto1" onclick="checkBox()" checked="false" />
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto2" onclick="checkBox()" checked="false" />
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto3" onclick="checkBox()" checked="false" />
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto4" onclick="checkBox()" checked="false" />
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto5" onclick="checkBox()" checked="false" />
<input id="inputBoxProducto3" />
```

Comment: Hola David, ¿podrías colocar un ejemplo? Necesitamos entender lo que deseas hacer para poder ayudarte, por ejemplo, colocando tu código de manera que podamos ejecutarlo y reproducirlo.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es utilizar querySelectorAll() y recorrer los checkbox y aplicarles un listener change asi cuando el estado de uno cambie poder atraparlo con evento.target y entonces validar si esta check o no para hacer el alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocurre porque Javascript se deja de ejecutar en cuanto se produce un error, dado que no existen dichos `checkbox` al intentar validar te arroja un error, puedes constatarlo en la consola.

```
if (checkBox.checked == true){  // error seguro si no existe
```

Debes validar primero que exista antes de acceder a cualquier atributo, prueba con alguna de estas opciones.

```
if (checkBox && checkBox.checked == true){ // <- esta es la forma recomendada

if (checkBox !== undefined && checkBox.checked == true){

if (typeof checkBox !== 'undefined' && checkBox.checked == true){
```

Generalmente funciona con la primera, pero no esta de mas mencionar otras alternativas.

Igual considera usar `===`  en lugar de `==`

El clásico ejemplo del porque no usar `==`:

```js
// USAR var SOLO POR COMPATIBILIDAD CON NAVEGADORES ANTIGUOS Y/O IE - EDGE
var num = 0;
var str = "0";

console.log(num == str); // true
console.log(num === str); // false
```